# How to change "size" of select when click on select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

sorry for my bad english, i have a problem with `select` :

```
<form name="reg" style="width:700px;" action="#" method="post">
 <p align="center"> 
    <select onChange="reg(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" size="1">
        <option selected value="250">Select the Reg</option> 
        <option value="0">Reg 1</option>
        <option value="1">Reg 2</option>
        <option value="2">Reg 3</option>
        <option value="3">Reg 4</option>
        <option value="4">Reg 5</option>
        <option value="5">Reg 6</option>
        <option value="6">Reg 7</option>
        <option value="7">Reg 8</option>
        <option value="8">Reg 9</option>
        <option value="9">Reg 10</option>   
    </select>        
 </p>   
</form>
```

I would like that when i click on select, the size of select changes in `size="5"`, because when the document load the size is `size="1"` (and this is good) but if i click on select, it shows all ten options, and this is the problem...
While, if i click on select, the size changes, is most beautiful.

**EDIT**
In future the form could have more 250 options, so is important that when the document load size is **1**, and when i click the size is **5** ....
**the size must be "5" only when the select show options, and when an option is selected the size must be 1.**

The problem is that i don't know how made it, maybe with jquery? or only with css?

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Native html elements are not very well suited for such detailed control. Take a look at jquery ui extensions like "chosen". They offer far more features than stock elements and typically look better too...

Comment: @1sand0s I thought the question was clear enough given the OP isn't a native english speaker, stop worrying about the points and think of your time spent helping the OP as time getting him closer to his goal. SO points are secondary to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working solution for your problem:

1. add focus event handler to the select list with id='selRegs'
2. set the size attribute to 6 (5 will show 4 options + the "Select the Reg" option)
3. after option is changed the size will be reset to 1
4. remove focus from select

https://jsfiddle.net/juaxo8zm/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var initPos = $("#yourDiv").position();
                console.log("init: ");
                console.log(initPos);
                $('#selRegs').focus(function () {
                    $('#selRegs').attr("size", "6");

                    $("#yourDiv").css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: initPos.top,
                        left: initPos.left
                    });                    
                });
                $('#selRegs').change(function () {
                    console.log("selected");

                    $('#selRegs').attr("size", "1");

                    $("#selRegs").blur();

                    $("#yourDiv").css({
                        position: "static"
                    });
                });
            });
```

I use jQuery for this:

[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

[.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

[.attr(param1, param2)](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

[.blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

[.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: but when i select an option the size must return size="1" ... in your example, also when i select an option, is always size="5" :/

Comment: yes thats what you asked for in your question: "In future the form could have more 250 options, so is important that when the document load size is 1, and when i click the size is 5 ...."

Comment: I edited the answer it should work now like you want it, tested in chrome, firefox and IE10

Comment: I edit the answer again. I removed the focus from the select after the option is seleted with .blur() function so the size wont have size=5/6 if the select is still focused. Now the answer should be complete. Please try it out and upvote if it is ok.

Comment: you are the winner :D is perfect :)  i have only very little problem, but i don't know that this there was not in the question : if i have a div under the form, when the options of select are show, the div goes down.. is there a way to do that the div doesn't goes down? if you don't ask at this little question, it is not a problem :) thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I edited the code. The div below won't move anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select size="1" 
    onfocus='this.size=5;' 
    onblur='this.size=1;' 
    onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)="myFunction()" event tag from the HTML select tag, or use jQuery [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) handler if you want to declare the event handler at the javascript level (I mean if you want add the additional event from javascript). 
I mean you have a choice - add the extra event dispatch code in the HTML tag source code or add it from the javascript/jQuery level.

The problem is that `onChange()` event dispatch doesn't get called until too late for your need (it gets called *after* a user selects a value).

You need to get notified the moment the button for the drop-down menu is clicked so you can change the selected value (default) value.

In your click function handler change the [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp) property and set it to the the index of the line that contains "5"

Comment: the problem is that i can't delete   onChange  and put onClick :/

Comment: @Rodrigoson6  if this approach works for you please up vote and accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to the answer. Thanks! Let me know if you have more questions to make this work.

Comment: i tried but doesn't work, if for you itsn't a problem, can you show me a little example? thanks

Comment: We put a lot of energy into steering you in the right direction and not a single up-vote for the effort. Why would anyone want to keep helping you?

Answer (score 0):

You should use click event on select

```
$('select').on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr('size',5) 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use javascript :

```
<select id='sel' onfocus='changesize();' onchange='changesize2();' size='1'>
    <option selected value="250">Select the Reg</option>
    <option value="0">Reg 1</option>
    <option value="1">Reg 2</option>
    <option value="2">Reg 3</option>
    <option value="3">Reg 4</option>
    <option value="4">Reg 5</option>
    <option value="5">Reg 6</option>
    <option value="6">Reg 7</option>
    <option value="7">Reg 8</option>
    <option value="8">Reg 9</option>
    <option value="9">Reg 10</option> 
</select>

<script>
function changesize(){
    document.getElementById('sel').size = '5';
}
function changesize2(){
    document.getElementById('sel').size = '1';  
    document.getElementById('sel').blur();
}
</script>
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxbRZb

Comment: That won't achieve the specific effect he was asking for.  It sounded like his question was how to change the default value at the moment of click.

Comment: but than the size is "5".. when i select a option, the size had to "1" and not "5"...

Comment: yes i would like to change the dafult value only at the moment of click. In this way it shows only five options, but than i select an option, it must show only one option (so size="1")

Comment: why don't you set size='5' at the first time ? then when one is selected, it's change to size='1' ?

Comment: yes @RenhardJulindra,  the size must be "5" only when the options are show. But when i select an option, the selecy must to show only one option (the selected option). Than, if i want to select another option, it must to show another time five options. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Rodrigoson6 You were not clear about all of that complexity in your question.  It is still a matter of intercepting onclick or onchange and then using Javascript or jQuery to modify the select DOM model (which I linked in my answer) to re-configure the contents of your select tag dynamically.

Comment: @Rodrigoson6 i have edit it, try it out. after you select an option, you need to click a blank space to reset the onfocus.

Comment: i tried doesn't work :/ the size (after i select an option) is always 5